# Realm and React Naitve with ios native part

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, react-native, realm

i have a question. I have already written app in js with react native and Realm database. Now i would migrate the database functionality to native code ios. How should i use Realm in this situation in native ios? Should i install realm pod and then in someway connect base from js and swift or in other way?

Comment: Did you find anything on this? Is it possible to share the same Realm DB between ios/Android native and React native?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can start from here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started